# Android vector graphics icon set

Tags: android, vector, vector-graphics

Anyone have a handy link where I can download the full Android vector-based icon set?

Answer (score 2):

They're not super well organized, but you may already have them in your `android-sdk/` directory (assuming you've downloaded your Android docs locally through your AVD Mannager).

Either in your:

```
docs/shareables/
                icon_templates-v1.0/
                icon_templates-v2.0/       
                sample_images/
                search_icons/
                (they all seem to be in Adobe Photoshop .psd format 
                stored in different layers)
```

or in your

```
docs/assets/images/
```

For their appendix, take a look at the local copy of your docs (here is the [online copy](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html))

```
docs/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, Looking around the web, I see https://android.git.kernel.org/ has quite a few sample apps too which have quite a few usable icons.

Comment: Yes, that's good too. Actually, take a look at this list. This seems to be the most comprehensive list, and I like the way it's set up. http://ntt.cc/2010/08/04/350-fresh-and-elegant-free-icons-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

would this be what you are looking for

http://www.matcheck.cz/androidguipsd/

Comment: Those are GUI mockups, not icons.